# Optimization INSERT with huge amount of data

Tags: java, mysql, performance

I'm using a `PreparedStatement` in a simple java console application to load Huge amount of data out of an `InputStream`.

This is the code:

```
public void readStopTimes(CSVReader reader) throws IOException, SQLException {
        String insertSql = "INSERT INTO stop_times VALUES (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement statement = db.prepareStatement(insertSql);
        String [] nextLine;
        long i = 0;
        Chronometer chronometer = new Chronometer();
        while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
            if(i++ != 0) {
                statement.setString(1, nextLine[0]);
                if(nextLine[1].isEmpty())
                    statement.setNull(2, Types.TIME);
                else
                    statement.setTime(2, Time.valueOf(nextLine[1]));
                if(nextLine[2].isEmpty())
                    statement.setNull(3, Types.TIME);
                else
                    statement.setTime(3, Time.valueOf(nextLine[2]));
                statement.setString(4, nextLine[3]);
                statement.setInt(5, Integer.parseInt(nextLine[4]));
                statement.addBatch();
            }
            if(i++ % 1000 == 0) {
                statement.executeBatch();
            }
            if(chronometer.count() > 5000) {
                chronometer.restart();
                log.debug("Analyzed {} rows", i);
            }
        }
        statement.executeBatch();
        db.commit();
    }
```

Every 1000 insertions i'm executing the batch, every 5 seconds i'm printing a log.

From the logs it's evident that this algorithm runs extremely fast at the beginning, counting a total of more than 4 million rows in the first 25 seconds, then it slow down, at the point that in 5 seconds only 2 rows gets added to the batch.

I need to insert more than 5 million rows, do you have a faster alternative?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but for test: can you add `statement = db.prepareStatement(insertSql);` after `statement.executeBatch();` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- disable query cache in mysql
- `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2` or if you can make sure that your mysql does not crash than make it `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0`
- if replication is enabled than disable the  syncing of bin log by doing `sync_binlog = 0`

you can try directly putting CSV file to MySql by `Load data infile . . . . .` command which is pretty fast.

Comment: Only valid solution is Load data infile, eventually pre-parsing file with java.

Answer (score 0):

Try comitting just after statement.executeBatch(); instead of just at the end. This should allow the inserts to be flushed as you proceed as mysql is keeping tabs on your inserts so it could roll them all back if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding data in multiple batches instead of a single batch. Commit after every batch and keep track of processed data. Or you can use a staging table to add the data to the table and once it is done, rename the table, in case of failure, restart or start from a save point.